# Difference between " " and ' ' in bash

Tags: command-line, echo

I am trying to figure out what is the difference between " " and ' '.

When I use them with `echo` they both give the same result,

```
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ echo Hello    world
Hello world
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ echo "Hello   world"
Hello   world
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ echo 'Hello   world'
Hello   world
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

Is there any specific situation where we need to use one or the other ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks for the help. I should have searched in stackoverflow as well once before posting the question here.

Comment: `echo -e 'single quotes $HOME \n'"\ndouble quotes $HOME"`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Comment: To reviewers considering closure: I think bash scripting is on-topic on Ask Ubuntu; plus, this question is of value. [The bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is a great resource, [that SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753) is quite valuable too, and both make clear which *syntactic* constructions get expanded inside `"` quotes. But they require looking through multiple sections of docs to figure out what *semantic* constructions (i.e., specifically what *kinds* of expansions) are usable in `"..."`. So I've tried to answer, from that perspective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) (Ubuntu's default interactive [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)), everything following an open single quote (`'`) is [quoted literally](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes), up until the next `'` which is taken as the closing quote. In contrast, several kinds of shell expansions are performed inside [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) (`"`).

- [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (with `$...` or `${...}`):

  ```bsh
  ek@Io:~$ echo '$HOME ${USER^^*} ${SHELL%%+([[:alnum:]])}'
  $HOME ${USER^^*} ${SHELL%%+([[:alnum:]])}
  ek@Io:~$ echo "$HOME ${USER^^*} ${SHELL%%+([[:alnum:]])}"
  /home/ek EK /bin/
  ```

  This is a common use case for `"` quotes in shell scripting. In particular, you may have seen [loops](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) that iterate through filenames, expanding a variable inside double quotes so it *does* get expanded but *doesn't* have its value split into separate words. For example, a command like this might help me keep track of things while preparing lots of media files for moving:

  ```bsh
  ek@Io:~$ for d in to\ *; do ls -ld "$d"; du -sh "$d"; done
  drwxr-x--- 856 ek ek 32768 Mar 29 10:47 to Albums (partial)
  308G    to Albums (partial)
  drwxrwxr-x 1191 ek ek 40960 Mar 11 12:56 to Books
  21G to Books
  ```
- [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) (with `$(...)` or `` `...` ``) and [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) (with `$((...))`):

  ```bsh
  ek@Io:~$ echo '$(date)      `uname -r`      $((2+2))'
  $(date)      `uname -r`      $((2+2))
  ek@Io:~$ echo "$(date)      `uname -r`      $((2+2))"
  Sat Apr  4 20:42:37 EDT 2015      3.19.0-11-generic      4
  ```
- [Escaping single characters with `\`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character) is supported and can be handy in `"` quotes, but is unsupported (and would generally be pointless) in the simpler `'` quotes:

  ```bsh
  ek@Io:~$ echo '$HOME \$HOME \\\\'
  $HOME \$HOME \\\\
  ek@Io:~$ echo "$HOME \$HOME \\\\"
  /home/ek $HOME \\
  ```
- [History expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) with `!` (if enabled, which it usually is when you're using the shell interactively):

  ```bsh
  ek@Io:~$ # this is just a comment (but I could run a command here)
  ek@Io:~$ echo '!!'
  !!
  ek@Io:~$ # this is just another comment (but could be another command)
  ek@Io:~$ echo "!!"
  echo "# this is just another comment (but could be another command)"
  # this is just another comment (but could be another command)
  ```

In addition, one of the most common reasons to use double quotes are to easily and intuitively quote text containing single quotes (since a `'` has no special meaning at all, inside `"` quotes):

```bsh
ek@Io:~$ echo "We'll have the dog's fleas gone soon, you'll see."
We'll have the dog's fleas gone soon, you'll see.
```

Finally, though you cannot escape a `'` inside `'`-quoted text, you can achieve the same result by *ending* quoting with `'`, using an escaped `'` (`\'`), and resuming quoting with `'`:

```bsh
ek@Io:~$ echo '"My $PATH ain'\''t what it used to be," said the stevedore'\''s apprentice.'
"My $PATH ain't what it used to be," said the stevedore's apprentice.
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated explaination. I have also changed the question by renaming 'Linux' to 'bash' to make it more correct question.

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow link posted above by bodhi.zazen answers this question.

Below is one situtation where it makes difference.

```
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ echo "Hello, I have only $((3+5)) $ in my account"
Hello, I have only 8 $ in my account
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ echo 'Hello, I have only $((3+5)) $ in my account'
Hello, I have only $((3+5)) $ in my account
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

Posting this answer, just to let others know that I've got the answer already. (I had posted this question .)

Thanks.

Comment: depending on what you are doing , you may wish to look at printf