# How to list files older than a day with "2015" in filename?

Tags: command-line, find

I want to list all the log files which do not belong to today and only the files that contain `2015` in their names.

These are the commands I have tried:

```bsh
find . -name 2015 -mtime +1 -exec  ls -ltrh  {} \;
```

```bsh
find . -name *2015* -mtime +1 -exec  ls -ltrh  {} \;
```

The output from both is nothing, but still, files are there. Something is wrong with these commands, and I am not getting what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `find` part looks good to me, but I also had problems with the `-exec` parameter. I couldn't get that to work either. (I was trying to move all jpg files from one folder to its parent directory through it - and ended up doing it manually...)

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days)

Comment: @steeldriver I think that's really what's going wrong here, since if there were files in the current directory with `2015` in their name (the other obvious shortcoming of the way the command is written) I suspect there would be *some* kind of output. So you might want to post an answer about that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*The command `find . -name '*2015*' -mmin +1440 -ls` will probably do what you want. See below for details.*

Your first command had `-name 2015`. It did not work because it finds *only* files whose names are *exactly* `2015`, with no other characters in them.

Your second command, `find . -name *2015* -mtime +1 -exec  ls -ltrh  {} \;`, might have failed for a couple of reasons:

#### **1.** Unquoted `*` characters are expanded by the shell, *then* passed on to `find`.

If there are any files directly contained in the *current* directory (the one you're in when you ran that `find ...` command) whose names contain `2015` (and don't start with a `.`), then the *shell* expanded `*2015*` into a list of those filenames, then passed that list as arguments to `find`. This is not what you want--instead, you want to pass `*2015*` literally as an argument to find, so that `find`, and not the shell, can find which files match it.

To fix that problem, quote `*2015*`. There are three common ways to do it:

- `'*2015*'` (i.e., `find . -name '*2015*' -mtime +1 -exec ls -ltrh  {} \;`)
- `"*2015*"` (i.e., `find . -name "*2015*" -mtime +1 -exec ls -ltrh  {} \;`)
- `\*2015\*` (i.e., `find . -name \*2015\* -mtime +1 -exec ls -ltrh  {} \;`)

I *suggest* writing it [with single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) as `'*2015*'`, because:

- [Quoting individual characters with `\`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character) can make it hard to see exactly what is being passed by the shell to the [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/find.1.html) command.
- [Quoting with `"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) sometimes involves [somewhat complicated rules](https://askubuntu.com/a/605440/22949).

But in this case it doesn't really matter. `'` and `"` both treat `*` the same and the expression isn't complicated enough for `\` quoting to make it hard to understand.

#### 2. `-mtime +1` only selects files modified *two or more* days ago.

As [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/find.1.html) says:

```
       Numeric arguments can be specified as

       +n     for greater than n,

       -n     for less than n,

       n      for exactly n.
```

```
       -mtime n
              File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the  comments
              for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
              of file modification times.
```

```
       -atime n
              File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When  find  figures  out
              how  many  24-hour  periods  ago the file was last accessed, any
              fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
              have been accessed at least two days ago.
```

Suppose a file was modified 47 hours ago. To figure out how many 24-hour periods that is, `find` rounds *down*: it is *one* 24-hour period ago. But `-mtime +1` matches only files whose modification times are *strictly more than* one 24-hour period ago. Thus files from yesterday are not matched.

See [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days) for more information, as [suggested by steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606569/list-files-older-than-a-day-with-string-2015-contains-in-filename#comment848830_606569).

To find files **last modified anytime more than 24 hours ago**, I suggest instead stipulating it as [1440 minutes ago](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20day%20in%20minutes) with `-mmin +1440`:

```bsh
find . -name '*2015*' -mmin +1440 -exec ls -ltrh {} \;
```

<sup>Some readers might be wondering why I did not quote `{}`. Some people quote `{}` to remind humans that it is not an expression for [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion). [Bourne-style shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell_compatible) (like [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)) *don't* require `{}` with nothing inside to be quoted. Maybe some non-Bourne-style shell does treat it specially; that might be why some users quote it. But there's also a *misconception* that one must sometimes quote `{}` so `-exec` handles filenames with spaces correctly. That;s false: with `{}` or `'{}'`, `find` gets the *same* arguments, as the shell [removes the quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal) before passing `'{}'` to `find`. To counter this misconception, I don't quote `{}`, but it's a matter of style--if you prefer `{}` to document how the shell isn't treating `{` and `}` specially, that's fine.</sup>

I recommend you also either change your [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/ls.1.html) command, or (as [muru has suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606569/list-files-older-than-a-day-with-string-2015-contains-in-filename#comment848816_606577)) replace it with `find`'s `-ls` action. **`ls -ltrh` is probably not doing what you intend** because it is run separately for each file found and thus the `-t` and `-r` flags, which specify sorting, are irrelevant.

Though the output will be formatted a bit differently than with `ls -l`, using `-ls` is simpler and easier.

```bsh
find . -name '*2015*' -mmin +1440 -ls
```

Or if you decide you really only need to list the file's names (including their paths, relative to `.`), you can simply specify no action, causing the default `-print` action to be used:

```bsh
find . -name '*2015*' -mmin +1440
```

Comment: Nice thorough answer! at least with GNU find, there's also the `newerXY` syntax, which accepts calendar arguments e.g. `-newermt 'yesterday'` and `! -newermt 'yesterday'`

Comment: You know what ? You are awesome.@Eliah Kagan

Comment: Thanks stell driver , thats very good information from the link to know. But in my case as it is application log from application old files got no way to get modified. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Quote the expression and I suggest you quote the brackets as well

```
find . -name "2015" -mtime +1 -exec  ls -ltrh  '{}' \;
```

or

```
find . -name "*2015*" -mtime +1 -exec  ls -ltrh  '{}' \;
```

you do not need to pass the files you find to ls

```
find . -name "*2015*" -mtime +1
```

Comment: Maybe restrict using `-type f`? And if `ls` has to be used, suggest using `-ls`.

Comment: sure, all good suggestions. I am not sure what the OP wants and I believe the source of the problem is the lack of quotes around the "-name" search pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In [zsh](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), you can use [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (this is a unique zsh feature, not available in other shells such as bash).

```
ls -ltr *2015*(m+1)
```

This only lists files in the current directory; to [traverse directories recursively](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing), use

```
ls -ltr **/*2015*(m+1)
```

With `find`, `-name 2015` only finds files whose name is exactly `2015`. `-name *2015*` only works if there are no files whose name contains `2015` in the current directory, because the shell expands the pattern `*2015*` before `find` is invoked. You need to quote the pattern:

```
find -name '*2015*' -mtime +1 …
```

Note that both `find -mtime +1` and zsh's `*(m+1)` find files that are **at least 48 hours old**, not files older than today. The plus sign means “strictly more than” and the number of days is rounded down. To find files that are at least 24 hours old, use `-mtime +0` or `(m+0)`.

If you want to find files that were last modified **yesterday or before**, you can use `find` with the [`-newermt` predicate](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Comparing-Timestamps.html#index-g_t_002dnewerXY-24):

```
find -name '*2015*' ! -newermt 'today 0:00' …
```

There's no really convenient way to make this test in zsh.